# MVC @Model with link redireting to localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, hyperlink, model, href

so I've got this code:

```
<li><a href="@Html.Raw(@Model.First().LinkTP)" target="_blank">@Html.Raw(@Model.First().LinkTP)</a></li>
```

The `LinkTP` is a string property that contains for example

> www.google.com

Instead of redirecting me to the site it redirects to:

> localhost:52638/www.google.com

What is the problem here? Model is a list.

@edit
Well, something is broken, even if href is `google.com` it still wants me to go through localhost/google.com..

Answer (score 0):

try this href need string only

```
<li><a href="@Model.First().LinkTP" target="_blank">@Html.Raw(@Model.First().LinkTP)</a></li>
```

Comment: I've already tried it like that.. no changes. Is there a way to put the name into a string inside razor code? and the use that variable in the href?

Comment: us javascript to put string in href

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answear, I have needed to put `http` tags inside href.